# PHP Stop warnings for 1 line of code

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following Warnings which SHOULD be there, but is there a way to stop them writting to the page without actually disabling Warnings globally?

Warnings:

> Warning: file_get_contents(E:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(F:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(G:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(H:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(I:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(J:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(K:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(L:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(M:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(N:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(O:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(P:/connected.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19

PHP Function:

```
//Check if the connection file is present on each drive
function scanDrives() {
    //Possible drives
    $letters = "DEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    $letters = str_split($letters);

    $code = md5("FMbHSBTMTXhu3TWp");

    //Check for a certain file on each device
    foreach($letters as $x) {
        $file = file_get_contents($x.":/connected.txt"); //This is what causes the error as the file can't be found.
        if ($file != false) {
            $file_code = split(":", $file);
            //Check if the file has the correct pass code
            if($file_code[0] == $code) {
                //Successful, return pass value and device letter and set name
                echo (1).",".$x.",".$file_code[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't just blindly open the file with `file_get_contents`.  Check to see if it exists first.

```
if(file_exists($x.":/connected.txt")){
    $file = file_get_contents($x.":/connected.txt");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is far better than using `@` suppression. +1

Comment: @FDL: I'll *never* suggest the `@` operator.  It's *always* better to check/handle errors than to just blindly ignore them :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Rocket Hazmat,

but to answer your question - in PHP you can use [Error Control operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) .. Specifically you can use the @ sign to ignore errors.

Simple Example

```
$file = @file_get_contents("file_doesnt_exist.php"); // wont throw any errors.
```

Comment: The Only time I've really used the @ operator is with DOMXpath to avoid xml/xhtml errors in other people's documents. It is useful to know, but always better to fix the errors instead of just push them under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "@" before the function that gives you the warning!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Yes it is true in fact! The solution of @RocketHazmat is better!